# .tflite model initializing the same detection boxes everytime

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, google-coral

I'm trying to implement a trained-from-scratch model onto a USB webcam attached to a google dev board. I cut the training at 15k. The model had not converged fully at 15k but I wanted to workout how to freeze the graph, tflite and move it onto a google coral dev board. I realise this may be an issue in terms of accuracy. MobileNetv2.

Below are that of a ceiling and a desk. The detection boxes appear in the exact same place each and everytime, no matter what the camera is looking at. The boxes do not move, nor does the percent change when the camera moves.

Train model

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

Freeze model

```
python export_tflite_ssd_graph.py --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix=training/model.ckpt-9070 --output_directory=inference_graph --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

Quantize

```
tflite_convert --graph_def_file=inference_graph/tflite_graph.pb --output_file=inference_graph/detect.tflite --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3 --mean_values=128 --std_dev_values=127 --allow_custom_ops --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6
```

The model is ran as follows on the google coral dev board;

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && edgetpu_detect \
--source /dev/video1:YUY2:1280x720:20/1  \
--model ${DEMO_FILES}/converted_tflite_quant_model.tflite
```

The google coral came prepacked with a demo facial recognition model (below). The only difference is the model. The below command works perfectly and tracks my face across the screen. The above command results in the photos below.

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && edgetpu_detect \
--source /dev/video1:YUY2:1280x720:20/1  \
--model ${DEMO_FILES}/mobilenet_ssd_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite
```

What could possibly be going wrong here?

Edit, a few months later, I've retrained it with mobilenet_v1, to the exact same result.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Humm,I wonder if the source camera could be a problem also?
Can you double check if the pixel format, size, and FPS values are correct?
Also, on both images that you posted, the process seems to be loading your `converted_tflite_quant_model.tflite` model, are you sure you tried other model?
Were you able to run the demo with the correct result?

Comment: Camera seems fine, v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/video1 is outputting correctly